# Does Oracle/MySQL proecess the task in multi thread model?

Tags: mysql, oracle, performance

Say I have below query with millions of records

```
 Select * from employee,department where employee.deptId=department.id
```

My question is will Oracle or MySQL spawn multiple threads to process the above single query? Basically scatter the single task and then gather the result or will there be a single thread for single process/query ?

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? These are two very different things.

Answer (score 1):

No.

MySQL does not split up any query into multiple threads / processes.  Note even for `UNION` or `PARTITION`.

If you have a very large dataset, then it may not matter -- you may be I/O-bound, hence limited by disk bandwidth, not CPU.

Your particular query is not a likely query to run since it would return millions of records -- the bottleneck may be the network and/or the client that is trying to receive "millions" of records.

Comment: Can you please elaborate `If you have a very large dataset, then it may not matter -- you may be I/O-bound, hence limited by disk bandwidth, not CPU.` Not sure what do you mean by it may not matter and I/O bound here ?

Comment: Also did not get `Your particular query is not a likely query to run since it would return millions of records -- the bottleneck may be the network and/or the client that is trying to receive "millions" of records` ? I believe you meant uery will run but client will take time to receive complete result set becoz oh high traffic on network?

Comment: I/O bound means the workload requires so much (disk) I/O compared to the amount of throughput that the disk subsystem can provide that the CPU is not the bottleneck and using multiple (or faster) cores would not improve performance.  Any given task is typically limited by only one factor -- the network, the disk,  or the processor, because when any one of these is saturated, the others can't be pushed any harder, because you are limited to the capacity of the one component that is saturated.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle RDBMS Enterprise Edition may do. Parallel processing is a big topic. Mostly it is used in datawarehouse or similar situations where you have a few users running very large queries, and is not used in OLTP where you have lots of users running very small queries.

Check your DB version, licence and the documentation for that under the topic parallel processing.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm